# Cover page behind HTML element using CSS ::before

Tags: html, css

I want to make a *modal dialog* and I want the background behind the dialog to be *grayed out* visually by a covering `DIV`. My problem is that the covering `DIV` also covers my dialog even though I style it with CSS's `::before` and it having a lower `z-index`; I would of course only want the `DIV` to cover the main form controls and not my dialog.

HTML:

```
<input text="Main form control example" type="text" />
<fieldset id="MainContent_fileExplorer_fsDialog" class="fileexplorer">
    <legend>File explorer</legend>
    <div id="MainContent_fileExplorer_pPath">
        <label for="MainContent_fileExplorer_txtFullPath">Path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="MainContent_fileExplorer_txtFullPath">
    </div>    
    <div>
        Form controls
    </div>
    <menu>
        <input type="submit" value="Ok" id="MainContent_fileExplorer_butSelect">
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="MainContent_fileExplorer_butCancel">
    </menu>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
/* File explorer fieldset */
fieldset.fileexplorer {
    color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 35%;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2em #888;
}

/* Gray out all elements except fieldset.fileexplorer */
fieldset.fileexplorer::before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: "";
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really possible without some dirty hacks. Here is a fiddle that works:

EDIT:(corrected a mistake in dom stucture, now it is a less "dirty hack")

http://jsfiddle.net/zqhnyo7s/1/

I used z-index: -1, which is not officially supported, but works.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;    
}

.main_form_input {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* File explorer fieldset */
fieldset.fileexplorer {
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2em #888;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

fieldset.fileexplorer:before {
    width: 1000%;
    height: 1000%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: fixed;
    left: -100%;
    top: -100%;
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: It did work to wrap the `FIELDSET` in a `SECTION` element and apply the CSS settings within `fieldset.fileexplorer:before` on the new `SECTION.fileexplorer` instead. I do like to keep the number of HTML elements down to a minimum but I guess this works ok.